# jQuery Mobile title limit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

What is the limit for jQuery mobile titles? How many characters? How do we change this limit? Working with jQuery mobile. Thanks.

Comment: Judging by the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js) (assuming you mean the dialog), there is no hard-coded limit. However,it would stand to reason that a title's length is limited by the amount of real estate on the screen that's available.

Comment: It's truncated on my iPhone, I guess my question is how to stop the truncation.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Getting Started with iPhone</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" /><script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script> </head>

Comment: @cuberds: Rotate your phone so it's landscape instead?

Comment: @cuberds: Are you talking jQuery mobile? I see this limiting to the first 14 characters in portrait (most likely leaving room for the navigation buttons)

Comment: @cuberds The code you have there is not jQuery UI, it's jQuery Mobile. The two are different - please edit your question if that is indeed the case.

Comment: Yes, jQuery mobile. So there's no solution other than the landscape workaround?

Comment: Landscape is not a workaround. jquery mobile does not let the text wrap to the new line. Put the text in a container and style it in a way that will cause wrapping. Should work if you know CSS well.

Answer (score 11):

You can override the left & right margins on the .ui-title class to give yourself some more space, but be careful because the margins are used to make sure the text doesn't interfere with any left & right buttons you have in the header.

```
.ui-header .ui-title { margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em; }
```

You might also get a bit more space using clip rather than elipsis:

```
.ui-header .ui-title { text-overflow: clip; }
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Lets hope this gets added as an option for when we know we're not using title buttons.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about your header/title being cut check out the following posts:

[How to stop your jQuery Mobile Header from being cut](http://operationmobile.com/how-to-stop-your-jquery-mobile-header-from-being-cut/)

[Stop your jQuery Mobile Header from being cut using white-space normal](http://operationmobile.com/stop-your-jquery-mobile-header-from-being-cut-using-white-space-normal/)

Comment: +1, solutions do not require modifying out-of-the-box CSS (but do pose similar risk of messing with appearance).

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but a google search took me here so I figured I'd post my solution for others.

I choose to override the CSS to force line wrapping, while reserving the space for buttons. I did so by adding

```
.ui-header .ui-title {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

to my css.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try to use non-breaking-spaces with this:

```
&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there should be any limit. You may go to any number of characters. It will simply wrap them as per screen size and will show ".." in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it won't wrap because the CSS for jQuery Mobile explicitly sets white-space to nowrap. This plus the margin and overflow settings gives you a usable space of about 30-40 characters before truncation.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution should be add white-space: normal to your text container

```
<div data-role="header">
  <h2 style="white-space: normal">Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text  </h2>
</div>
```