# Why is my header text being truncated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page built with jQuery mobile with header markup that looks like this:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>The Magnet Puzzle</h1>
</div>
```

I tested it out in an Android and a Windows phone, and in both it truncates the last three characters of the header text, even though the header is wide enough to fit the entire title:

[image: turncated header]

I want it to look like this instead:

[image: full header text]

Why is it being truncated, and how can I fix it so that it displays the entire title?

Comment: Are you sure the header is wide enough. Have you checked the: `width`, `margin` and `padding`?

Comment: @PeeHaa Look at the header strip. Look at the width of the text. Does it look wider than the header to you?

Comment: it's pretty hard to see `padding` by looking at some image :P

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think the real trouble is that JqMobile is setting the left and right margin to 30% leaving only 40% of the total width for your title.  Change that to 10% and you get the ellipsis when you really need it.

```
.ui-header .ui-title {
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Why would they set the default margins at 30%?

Answer (score 10):

It's being truncated because of jQuery Mobile's CSS for `.ui-header .ui-title`, which sets the `overflow` to `hidden`, the `white-space` to `nowrap` and the `text-overflow` to `ellipsis`.

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this, but you can override the jQuery mobile CSS like so:

```
.ui-header .ui-title {
  overflow: visible !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

[This question has been asked before with the same answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199977/jquery-mobile-title-limit)

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to do something like that

Comment: @PeterOlson: I updated my answer with a link to a previous question concerning the jQuery Mobile title.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your `<h1>` in a `<div>`:

```
    <div data-role="header">  
        <div><h1>The Magnet Puzzle</h1></div>  
    </div>
```

(Then center the h1 with your preferred CSSery.)

Comment: Sorry, but the standard layout includes the DIV + H1 wrapping and it truncates.  It's the ".ui-header .ui-title { margin-right: 10%; margin-left: 10%; }" style override for the win.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all the suggested solutions, always failing.

I could solve the problem editing the jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css.

Use your text editor find function to find this:

```
margin:.6em 30% .8em;
```

and comment it :

```
/* margin:.6em 30% .8em; */
```

Worked perfectly for me on jquery mobile 1.3.1 (used locally, of course).

Answer (score 1):

add in your file

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-header .ui-title {margin: 0 20%}
</style>
```

to change the default margin of header.

Answer (score 0):

This is done with CSS.

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Remove this from the JqMobile CSS or overwrite it with your own.

Answer (score 0):

Your `viewport` meta must fit with the device screen. Add into the `<head>` :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,
minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, 
target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

All details and explanations here :

[Anatomy of a Jquery Mobile Page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a dead thread but still...

Just use `<p style="text-align:center">` instead of `<h1>` and you should be fine(Only for dialogs).

```
<div data-role="header">
    <p style="text-align:center">The Magnet Puzzle</p>
</div>
```