# JQM popup header too short

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

When I put something like `<h1>Confirm deletion for operator named not extremely long</h1>` to popup as header, finally in popped up window I see truncated header 'Confirm deletion for...'.
That's not I want to see here.
Which option responsible for showing headers "as-is"?

Comment: Please take this into your consideration... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718384/why-is-my-header-text-being-truncated

Comment: Try looking at this link:



 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718384/why-is-my-header-text-being-truncated

Comment: Clear. As for me - manipulations with margin-right and margin-left are enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override style of class `ui-title`, for example

```
.ui-title {
 padding-left: 5px !important;
 padding-right: 5px !important;
 margin:5px !important;
 white-space: normal !important;
 font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/p2d6P/)**